# Importing a component into Vue router not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue app(v2.5) that I am in the process of converting into an SPA w/vue router. I wish to organize my templates for the routes into separate files and import them into my index.js for the router to consume. The problem is I am getting an error Message:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in
---> <Anonymous>
       <Root> vue.common.js:593
```

When I include the template in the index.js file all is well. The app is built w/Browserify that is why I am importing w/require instead of es6 imports.
Files:

```
// src/router/index.js
const Vue = require("vue");
const VueRouter = require("vue-router");
const home = require("../js/components/homeComponent");

    const routes = [
      {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: home,
      },
    ];
    
    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: "history",
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes,
    });
    
    module.exports = router;


// src/components/homeComponent.js
const Vue = require("vue");

const Home = Vue.component("home", {
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      
      <h1 class="text-center inset-shadow">Scores From Around The Leagues</h1>
      <div id="sportsImages" class="title-images d-inline-flex justify-content-around fixed-top">
        <img src="./src/img/mlb-sm.jpg" alt="Pitcher Throwing Ball" />
        <img src="./src/img/nfl-sm.jpg" alt="David Tyree Superbowl Catch" />
        <img src="./src/img/nba-sm.jpg" alt="Michael Jordan Dunking" />
      </div>

      <hr class="my-2" />
            
    </div> <!-- End .container -->
   `,
});

module.exports = {
  Home
};
```

I console logged home in index.js and see:

```
Object { Home: VueComponent(options)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: module.exports =  Home;

Comment: That's what you get for copy/paste w/o thinking what you are doing. Mucho appreciado. Curious, do I even need to declare it as a template? Router Docs example shows just a template literal will suffice it seems.